# PageMenuKitSwiftを使用しているのですがFontSizeの変え方がわかりません。

Tags: swift, ios, swift4, swift5

[PageMenuKitSwift](https://github.com/magickworx/PageMenuKitSwift)を使用しているのですが、
PageMenu部分(下の画像の"May,June,July")のフォントサイズを変えることができません。

[image: PageMenuKitSwift Example]
githubより引用

よろしければ、ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースコードを確認したところ `PMKPageMenuItemDesign` を使うことで文字色やテーマ色を変更できそうでしたが、フォントサイズに関しては該当する処理が見当たらないため、フォントサイズの変更に関しては機能として提供されていないと思います。

OSSとして公開されているものですのでフォントを変更するロジックを追加するか、または直接PageMenuKitSwiftのソースコードを変更する必要がありそうです。

もし後者の方法で対応するのであれば、質問に添付されている画像のテーマは `.plain` が指定されており、表示には `PMKPageMenuItemPlain` が使われています。以下のように renderメソッドを修正することで、フォントサイズを変更できます。

```swift
public class PMKPageMenuItemPlain: PMKPageMenuItem {
  // 中略

  override func render(active: Bool) {
    self.label.textColor = active ? self.design.titleColor : .darkGray
    self.label.backgroundColor = .clear

    // ↓ フォントサイズを変更する
    self.label.font = active ? .systemFont(ofSize: 20) : .systemFont(ofSize: 10)
  }
}
```

実行すると下図のように表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]